# How do you build the x64 Boost libraries on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, boost, 64-bit, boost-build

I've built the x86 Boost libraries many times, but I can't seem to build x64 libraries. I start the "Visual Studio 2005 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt" and run my usual build:

```
bjam --toolset=msvc --build-type=complete --build-dir=c:\build install
```

But it still produces x86 .lib files (I verified this with dumpbin /headers).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to add the `address-model=64` parameter.

Look e.g. [here](http://devsql.blogspot.com/2007/05/building-boost-134-for-x86-x64-and-ia64.html).

Comment: This answer is also valid for the newer boost build tool, `b2`.

Comment: can you explain this then?    C:\Boost\boost_1_61_0>.\b2 --stagedir=lib\x64 architecture=x86  address-model=64  link=static --build-type=complete stage
Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : yes

Comment: It seems that ```address-model``` does not show in the output of ```b2 --help``` (b2 4.3) , how can I get help of it from commandline ?

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is correct. Adding this in case somebody else googles this answer and still fails to produce x64 version.

Following is what I had to do to build Boost 1.63 on Visual Studio 15 2017 Community Edition.

Commands executed from VS environment cmd shell. Tools -> Visual Studio Command Prompt

```
C:\Work\Boost_1_63> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat amd64
C:\Work\Boost_1_63> bootstrap.bat
C:\Work\Boost_1_63> bjam -j4 architecture=x86 address-model=64 link=static stage
C:\Work\Boost_1_63> bjam --prefix=C:\opt\boost architecture=x86 address-model=64 link=static install
```

You can verify that the resulting .lib is x64 with dumpbin:

```
C:\Work> dumpbin /headers C:\work\boost_1_63\stage\lib\libboost_locale-vc140-mt-1_63.lib | findstr machine
8664 machine (x64)
8664 machine (x64)
8664 machine (x64)
8664 machine (x64) 
...
```

Answer (score 3):

With b2 the command is:

```
b2 --build-dir=build/x64 address-model=64 threading=multi --build-type=complete --stagedir=./stage/x64
```

It will show `default address-model: 32-bit` at the beginning but will still build in 64-bit (how confusing).You should have the dlls created with names such as `library-vc140-mt-x64-1_71.dll` confirming it is 64-bit.

source: [Building Boost 32-bit and 64-bit libraries on Windows](http://informilabs.com/building-boost-32-bit-and-64-bit-libraries-on-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

You may find following [Boost.Build property](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.overview.invocation.properties):

```
address-model=64
```