# Boost Linker Issues

Tags: boost, linker-errors, clion, boost-program-options

I am using the Boost library and I am having some linker issues. Currently my code is outputting this:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "boost::program_options::to_internal(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&)", referenced from:
> std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > > > boost::program_options::to_internal<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > >(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > > > const&) in train_model_main.cc.o
> "boost::program_options::variables_map::variables_map()", referenced from:
> _main in train_model_main.cc.o (THE LIST CONTINUES)

At the bottom my code says this:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am trying to use the program_options library from Boost, but the linking step seems to be failing. Here is how I link in my CMake file:

```
find_package(Boost 1.73.0 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_executable(main ./apps/something.cc)
    target_link_libraries( main program_options)
endif()
```

I believe that I am correctly linking the library, so what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna copy and paste the answer from the cmake discourse:
https://discourse.cmake.org/t/boost-linker-issues/2030

"I believe that I am correctly linking the library” unfortunately not. You need to reference the full target name including the namespace prefix with Boost::program_options. And you can omit adding the Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS explicitely as the target definition does include this information. So your lines would look like:" - Volker Enderlein

```
if(Boost_FOUND)
    add_executable(main ./apps/something.cc)
    target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC Boost::program_options)
endif()
```

Comment: Just tried this, but it didn't work. Will try asking on the discourse.

Answer (score 0):

Mismatch of architecture is the issue here. Match your compile of the application you are building with the boost program options

[How do you build the x64 Boost libraries on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302208/how-do-you-build-the-x64-boost-libraries-on-windows/302257)

The address needs to be set to 64 in your case or use 64 bit binaries